# Easy Limit not working

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why is this limit not working?

```
Limit[I*Sin[alpha^0.5*Betta]*Sin[Lc*Betta*alpha^0.5]/(alpha^0.5*Betta),alpha -> 0]
```

If I remove the division by alpha it works fine, but it doesn't if I divide the two Sines by alpha

Comment: try `(1/2)` or `Sqrt` instead of `0.5`

Comment: @george2079 Actually, if I change only one of the two 0.5 into 1/2 (leaving the other one 0.5) I get a result. Weird? The weirdest thing is that I dont need to change both 0.5 in 1/2.

Comment: Btw, that greek letter you are referring to is not called `Betta`. Actually, it is called `Bettina` and it looks like this `♀` :)

Comment: @george2079 Do you know why it fails with `0.5`?

Comment: Its typical that using inexact real numbers (.5) for things that should be mathematically exact cause such problems. Its not always predictable of course, `Limit[Sin[x^.5]/x^.5,x->0]` works when you might expect it should not.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting this way we can reach for some result:

```
Limit[I*Sin[Sqrt[α]*β]*(Sin[Lc*β*Sqrt[α]]/(Sqrt[α]*β)),α->0]
```

> 0